# Are there any good software tools for teaching history?

Tags: discussion

I hope all is well.  I'm a father of three young children ages 5, 6 and 10.  I'm also a software engineer and have been coding and writing software for many years.

I noticed that English and math teachers are lacking some important tools for teaching and, after looking through of what services are offered from various companies, I decided to fill in the holes where I think other companies missed in terms of meeting the needs of teachers.  For the past many months or so, I have been in my little corner learning and coding.

What I want to do now is I want to evaluate my software as it relates to teaching history to K-12.  First off, are there any -- good -- tools and/or services for the teachers to teach history?  If so, can you tell me a few of them that you use?

I know it's an odd question since typically technology and history have been apart.  After all, it's a lot easier to relate physics with technology due calculations and simulations than to relate history with technology.  But I think I have something specifically for history teachers to make their lives easier.  So if you can fill me in with the technology that you use as it relates to history, I would be thankful.

Comment: I'm old enough that I can remember [Oregon Trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Oregon_Trail_%28video_game%29) being sold as the best software available for teaching history.

Comment: Posts should only be moved to meta if they are about [History.SE or the SE engine](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). This appears to be off-topic for meta. Meta is not the place to dump questions that are off-topic on the main site.

Comment: Seems this should either be on History.SE or [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Europa Barbarorum](http://www.europabarbarorum.com/) is a (free) total conversion mod for CA's turn based strategy game Rome Total War. It's one of the few games aiming to be historically correct. The creators expressed that they believe the game can be used as a teaching tool as well. It covers the history of Europe, North Africa, the Arabian peninsula and the middle east between 272 BC and 15 AD. There are similar mods that cover the medieval period (have a look at [mod db](http://www.moddb.com/games/medieval-ii-total-war-kingdoms/mods)) but i have yet to find one with the same level of accuracy.